# How to combine 4 html pages into 1 page?

Tags: html

I've got a static website(4 pages) that only talks to firebase and has few images.
https://github.com/wave-rider/StroopEffect
Is there any way to compile/convert it into one HTML page with all images embedded into the page as strings and also make links between the pages working?

Comment: You are looking for a SPA framework. Take a look at React, Angular, or VueJS.

Comment: "compile/convert it into one HTML page" can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Do you mean you want one file, or do you want to hide the navigation between pages?
As for the embedded images, look into [DATA URI's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: @Stanislas Yes, I want to have just one page with all resources in it

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Thank you. I will have a look at them. I know a bit of Angular and did a bit of research online. Does Angular always require node.js. Can I create a static app, do you know?

Comment: The only reason Angular "requires" nodejs is for it to be able to locally build your project. You wouldn't be interacting with nodejs yourself, it's just a dependency of the angular toolchain. I'd like to suggest React though -- as it requires less 'upfront' learning to use.

Comment: Ok then, I will do it in Angular. I will put into github once it is done.

Comment: Can I also ask you a favor please? My son cloned a statistical experiment involving the Stroop effect.
If you can afford to take some time out of your day and go through the test it would be very appreciated by my son. The test is completely anonymous(and the only thing being recorded is the time it takes you to finish the tests. https://wave-rider.github.io/StroopEffect/. We are trying to collect as much data as possible. Thanks a lot for your answers on my post.